How to make a shared library's global object survive exit() function?
I have a problem with a shared library's global object getting destroyed before it is used. I do not know all details nor do I have control over an application that uses the library but my assumption about what is happening is this:

the application's main() function returns
exit() function gets called
exit() destroys the global object
exit() calls atexit-functions, that is functions registred with atexit() function
atexit-functions call the library's functions, which use the global object, which was already destroyed

I need the object to survive that.
Will dynamic creation solve the problem? Any of these:
Object *pObj = new Object;
Object &rObj = *(new Object);

As I understand, a dynamically created object would survive. But what about variables that point to the object? pObj and rObj are global variables themselves. Would not they be destroyed before atexit-functions the same way an object with static storage duration gets destroyed?

Global objects are destroyed in the reverse order in which they were created. The solution is, therefore, to ensure that all users of the object are created after the object that they use.

Your assumption is correct! global objects in shared libraries may be destroyed before any atexit-functions that reference them are called.  one way you can try static Object *pObj = new Object; to avoid this problem. This way, the object will only be created the first time it’s needed, and it won’t be destroyed until the application actually terminates.

"I have a problem with a shared library's global object getting destroyed before it is used." - ¿Are you sure that this is your problem and not the problem of whoever uses this library in inappropriate manner? ¿Does library interface explicitly allow such tricky scenarios as calls from atexit  handlers? ¿Have you considered altering library interface?

I recommend avoid having global objects, instead have a static (internal to your translation unit) pointer.  Your library could have a initialize() that sets up all its state by newing up your pointer to have its global state object, and a terminate() to tear all that down (delete that global pointer, and set it to nullptr).

@j6t, The indirect users of the object are atexit-functions which are registered before the object is created. It can not be changed for the purpose of this question.

@SheltonLiu, I guess my question now is when a pointer is destroyed? I just need confirmation that global pointers are not destroyed the same way as global objects before atexit-functions are called.

@user7860670, If there is an easy solution I would rather implement it.



exit() destroys the global object
exit() calls atexit-functions, that is functions registred with atexit() function


Not exactly. Destruction of global objects and calls to atexit-functions may be interleaved. The order depends on the order of construction of the global objects and calls to atexit.

[basic.start.term/5]
If the completion of the initialization of an object with static
storage duration strongly happens before a call to std​::​atexit
(see <cstdlib>,
support.start.term), the
call to the function passed to std​::​atexit is sequenced before the
call to the destructor for the object. If a call to std​::​atexit
strongly happens before the completion of the initialization of an
object with static storage duration, the call to the destructor for
the object is sequenced before the call to the function passed to
std​::​atexit.

So if you always call std::atexit after all global objects referenced in the atexit-function are constructed, you should be fine.
To be absolutely sure, you can use the nifty counter idiom.

All "bad" atexit-functions are registered before loading the library. I do not have control over that. Nifty counter is not going to help either. It is just a wrapper which will be destroyed before atexit-functions and in its destructor it destroys a global object which it wraps. Now, it can be changed so the global object is not destroyed, but it is just dynamic creation with extras.

If atexit is called before the library is loaded, and exit is called immediately after, what happens? The atexit-function cannot touch the global object because it doesn't exist yet. You need to return to this exact state after the library is unloaded.

Well, I guess the application and/or other libraries it depends on track their internal state and know whether the library was loaded and, if not, they will not call the library's functions. I am going to use dynamic creation, I think. It is simple to implement and seems to work.

Well if unloading the library doesn't bring the application to an internal state similar to that it had before loading the library, then there is a bug in the application. Dynamic allocation may be an easy workaround, but it's a workaround and not really a fix.

After thinking about it some more, I am now convinced that the nifty counter will work with atexit just fine.
